# Arbitrary Precision Floating Point library for High Level Synthesis

Tags: c++, templates, floating-point, floating-point-precision, arbitrary-precision

I am trying to make a template based arbitrary precision floating point library in C++ which supports variable Exponents and variable Mantissa which can be specified as template arguments. I have already developed a template based Fixed Point library. The type of implementation I want is :

```
 template<int EXPONENT_BITS, int MANTISSA_BITS>
     struct fp_float
         {
           <some_data_type_to_store_exponent_and_mantissa_values>;
         };
```

I am unable to find a suitable datatype to store the exponents so that I don't use more bits than needed for the code. I thought of using `intn_t` where `n = {8, 16, 32, 64}` but then if I declare `fp_float<3,11>` it will use `8` bits for the `EXPONENT` and `16` bits for `MANTISSA`.

Hence it makes the entire library useless as it uses more resources than it ought to for a specified precision.

I would like to know if there is any other arbitrary precision data-type that serves my purpose.

I did come across a few arbitrary precision libraries but these libraries have some code structure that cannot be synthesized into Hardware Descriptions using High Level Synthesis (which is the reason I am making this library).

Comment: @Bathsheba : I did go through `Boost`,  `MPFR` , `ttmath` and `GMP` and tried to synthesize them to hardware Descriptions , but they all use several code implementations that aren't supported by High Level Synthesis tools like Vivado. The fact that I have to make the library synthesize compatible is the reason I am building it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a valid solution for you? base_int_t is a trait type that gives you the basic type to be used in the subsequent bitfield definition. The code below is missing the specializations for N > 2

```
// gives an integer type fitting in N bytes
template <int N>
struct base_int_t
{
    typedef int type;
};
// specializations
template <>
struct base_int_t<1>
{
    typedef unsigned char type;
};

template <>
struct base_int_t<2>
{
    typedef unsigned short type;
};
// add suitable definitions for N = 3,4...8. For N = 3 and 4 type is unsigned int

template <int EXP_BITS, int MANTISSA_BITS>
struct fp_float
{
    // template argument is the number of bytes required
    typedef typename base_int_t<(EXP_BITS + MANTISSA_BITS + 7) / 8>::type type;
    type mantissa : MANTISSA_BITS;
    type exponent : EXP_BITS;
};

typedef fp_float<3, 11> fp_3_11_t;
fp_3_11_t fp;
```

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot. , but once I go past 16 , it again has its own shortcomings. But its definitely a good hack for low bit-widths.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ac_int from ac_datatypes by Mentor Graphics.

https://www.mentor.com/hls-lp/downloads/ac-datatypes

It is free and usable as well in simulation and in HLS.